# C++ Check that in a string only exist following characters

Tags: c++, string, iterator, compare

The valid charaters are

// ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main();
{
  bool bIsValid = true;

  // test characters
  string strCheck("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_/");
  string s("foo@?+baa") ; // should bring a "false" because of the "@?+" characters

  string::const_iterator it = strCheck.begin();

   // this is NOT a clever soulution has anybody a better idea ?   
   while (s.find(*it) != string::npos) 
   {
     ++it;

     if(!s.find((*it))
     {
       bIsValidKey = false;
       break;
     }

   }

cout << "Is Valid: " << bIsValid << endl ;

}
```

My problem is how can a get the first charater after the iteratorpoint to compare
with the allowed charactes. I need something like (*it).first_charater_after to
solve the problem.

Dos anybody has an other idea to check that in the string only exists a defined
number of charaters?

Comment: Please fix that `if(!s.find((*it)))`

Comment: where is the problem with the bracked if(!s.find((*it)))? I know that there have to be (*it).somthing() but what?

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the regex library: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/
or google c++ rexexp.
It might require some learning, but once mastered it saves lots of time.

Comment: <regex> is a good idea, i will see.

Comment: I posted an example with regex. It's quite flexible, and you don't have to type all the valid characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  bool bIsValid = true;

  string s("GHHbaa111__") ; // Add/remove other characters

    regex r("^[[:alnum:]_]*$");

    if (regex_match(s,r)) {
        cout << "Valid string" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Invalid string" << endl;
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `string::find_first_not_of`?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  bool bIsValid = true;

  // test characters
  std::string strCheck("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_/");
  std::string s("foo@?+baa") ; // should bring a "false" because of the "@?+" characters

  if (s.find_first_not_of(strCheck) != std::string::npos)
    bIsValid = false;

  std::cout << "Is Valid: " << bIsValid << std::endl ;
}
```